# SSRS Report Builder, is there a way to show values in filter?

Tags: reporting-services

Is there anyway to show the user what values are in each field so they can filter on these values?

How is the user supposed to know what values they want to filter if they can't see the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you are asking:
1) Set up a data set to retrieve the available values for your filter

```
SELECT DISTINCT MyFieldValue FROM MyTable
```

2) Create an SSRS parameter which will be used for the user to select a filter. Set it up to allow multiple values, and set the available values to use the data set created in step 1. Let's call this Step2Parameter.

3) Create your core data set for the report, and use the parameter from step 2.

```
Select MyID, MyFieldValue, Name, Blah FROM MyTable WHERE MyFieldValue in ( @Step2Parameter )
```

You can repeat this with multiple fields.

Does that get you in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure that in the Parameter Properties (right click your parameter and select Parameter Properties), that "Select Parameter Visibility" in the "General" menu is set to "Visible".